# How does multimeter AC measurement work?

Tags: ac, measurement, multimeter

How does a digital multimeter measure AC voltage? My guess would be that the AC voltage is rectified and filtered into a DC voltage which is then measured, giving the peak voltage of the AC signal. Am I correct?

A follow up question: I remember reading from somewhere that multimeters cannot very well give accurate AC voltage measurements if the signal is not a sinusoid but a square wave for example. Is this true? If so, why is this? If AC measurement works by rectification into DC as I assume, shouldn't they measure other types of waveforms just as well?

Comment: See if my answer to [Average value of current or voltage](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/328185/average-value-of-current-or-voltage/328198#328198) helps.

Comment: Before digital, the D'Arsonval meter movement would effectively average the rectified voltage swings. Cheap digital multimeters probably also rectify the input and attempt to find the peak value from which they can work out in a digital way the same thing. For a sine wave only, \$\overline{V}=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^{\pi}\,V_\text{PK}\operatorname{sin}\left(\theta\right)\,\text{d}\theta=\frac{2}{\pi}V_\text{PK}\approx 0.637\cdot V_\text{PK}\$. Other waveforms would have different results of that integral and therefore such meters would have various intrinsic errors in their measurement.

Answer (score 4):

First, I'll note an erroneous assumption: AC meters do not display peak voltage but rather RMS voltage. This is a sort of "average" voltage that makes all the math work out right.

Now, to answer the question:

There are two main methods of doing AC measurement: the cheap way, and the accurate way.

The cheap way is indeed how you suspect: rectify it and measure the peaks, and then divide by √2 to get the RMS. This works only for sinusoids, because the factor of √2 implicitly assumed a sinusoidal signal.

The accurate way uses what's called a "true RMS converter", which is a circuit (analog in older true RMS meters, probably digital in modern ones but don't quote me on that) that actually calculates the RMS voltage with appropriate signal processing techniques.

Comment: If my multimeter uses the cheap way, can I measure peak voltages of non-sinusoids by simply multiplying the output reading of the MM by the square root of 2?

Comment: @S.Rotos Yes, and no. You would need to multiply by a correction factor that is dependent upon the specific type of non-sinusoidal waveform you are measuring. \$ \sqrt{2} \$ is the factor that ties the peak of a sinusoid to the RMS of a sinusoid. You need other factors if you want to tie the RMS of a sinusoid to the peak of a non-sinusoid.

Comment: It's not \$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}V_\text{peak}\$ but instead \$\frac{2}{\pi}V_\text{peak}\$ for averaging meters that assume a rectified sinusoid.

Comment: @jonk I might just be tired, but isn't \$V_{rms} = \frac{V_{pk}}{\sqrt{2}}\$?

Comment: @Hearth I think you need more sleep.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I did some measurements, and I noticed that the measurement given by the MM is highly frequency dependent; I inserted a square wave into the MM (as the RMS voltage of a square wave is equal to to peak voltage) and I got correct voltages at lower frequencies (I verified with an oscilloscope) but over around 4kHz the output given by the MM was nearly halved (while the measurement given by the scope stayed the same). What would be the cause of this effect?

Comment: @S.Rotos They don't design multimeters, generally, to work on high-frequency AC because the main purpose of them is to measure mains-frequency things.

Comment: @DKNguyen Are you sure? I went and looked it up to be sure and in the case of a sinusoid, the RMS voltage is Vpk/√2 according to every source I have. Of course that's only sinusoids, but I'm not sure where jonk's 2/π comes from...

Comment: @Hearth I provided the complete equation as a comment to the OP. You can agree with it or disagree. If disagree, explain why. If agree, you are forced to the same conclusion. If you look on the web for ".637" or ".6366" in this context, you will google up pages and pages on the topic, as well. Keep in mind that I'm discussing ***rectified*** AC.

Comment: @Hearth In case a mere hobbyist is a poor source for you, here's a [page](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/accircuits/average-voltage.html) that provides a similar discussion and may be taken with better authority. (But I think the statement is easy to just write out quickly.)

Comment: @Hearth Nothing wrong with what you said, but nothing wrong with what Jonk said either. But you guys were talking about different things. I was referring to your sleepy eyes missing that Jonk was talking about AVG, not RMS.

Answer (score 2):

Cheap meters measure the average rectified value and then jimmy the reading up (modify the calibration - gain vs. ADC reference voltage- so that it reads higher than the actual measured voltage) by ~+11.1% to correctly read RMS for a pure sine wave. They read the incorrect RMS value of any waveform other than a sine wave (usually they are AC coupled too, so any DC component is ignored). A square wave would tend to be displayed too high because the average is equal to the RMS.

For a sine wave of peak voltage Vp:

The average over a half cycle is 2Vp/\$\pi\$ = 0.6366 Vp

The RMS is Vp/\$\sqrt{2}\$ = 0.707107 Vps

The ratio is \$\pi \over 2\sqrt{2}\$ \$\approx\$ 1.11072

More expensive meters attempt to measure the RMS value (the square root of the average of the squared voltage). Typically that's done with an analog chip and it will only handle some range of crest factor (ratio of peak to RMS) and bandwidth without losing a lot of accuracy.

Comment: Could you please clarify "jimmy" for our readers? I'm from the midwest US and I knew what you meant, but it sounds like a colloquialism.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson Done. I do try to stick-handle those colloquialisms. 8-)

Answer (score 0):

> If AC measurement works by rectification into DC as I assume, shouldn't they measure other types of waveforms just as well?

Regardless if the measurement is based on peak value or the average level of the rectified waveform, you discard information in these processes. The RMS value is related to power, so it depends on the squared value of the voltage at each instant. This squaring can be performed digitally or with analog circuits, and must be later averaged.

Also important: when you choose "AC" only, the multimeter removes any DC component in the signal *before* rectification. Only then it takes the peak or average value if it is not a True-RMS device.

Think what will happen with a square wave an notice that you must know how your device works to convert the value of non sinusoidal signals.